# What is the difference between port number 80 and 443?

Tags: workflow

I know port number 443 is for SSL and certification (hhtps), but I think the reason that I cannot register workflow client/workflow manager is that I do not know what is their action in workflow manager configuration.
If I insert port number 443 when I am creating a web application instead of 80, then how I have to configure workflow manager in registration step???